# How can I to use an AWS temporary security credential just one time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sts

I want to send a **temporary security credentials** to a user who can use this credential just **one time** and after that it will be disabled.

When I want to create a temporary security credentials, I only have the option to specify an expiry time. But I want to allow this user to use this credential just one time to send data to Amazon SQS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard **AWS Security Token Service (STS)**.

STS is used to generate **time-limited credentials**, but it is not possible to limit credentials by "number of uses".

You would need to write an **"in-between" application** that would receive the request, check that it is the first request, and then forward the request to SQS using its own credentials. This application could be run on EC2, your own computer somewhere on the Internet, or even on **AWS Lambda** via the **Amazon API Gateway**. However, you would need to write such an application.